# Flex items wrapping even with box-sizing border-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my code below, when I add padding it should add to width since I am using `border-box`. But it is not working why? Can anyone help me.

If I add some margin or padding my `child__wrapper` is pushed into new line why?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.child__wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 33.3%;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child__wrapper">1</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">2</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">3</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">4</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">5</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">6</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">7</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">8</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that `box-sizing: border-box` brings padding and borders into the width / height calculation, *but not margins*. Margins are always calculated separately.

The [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property takes two values:

- `content-box`
- `border-box`

It does not offer `padding-box` or `margin-box`.

Consider those terms when referring to the [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html).

[image]

<sup>source: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html)</sup>

So when you set your item widths to 33.3% and add 10px margins on the right and left, an overflow condition is triggered, resulting in a wrap of the third item.

```
33.3% + 33.3% + 33.3% + 10px + 10px + 10px + 10px + 10px + 10px > 100%
```

Instead, try this on the items:

```
flex: 1 0 26%
```

This shorthand rule breaks down to this:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 0`
- `flex-basis: 26%`

With `flex-grow: 1` there's no need for `flex-basis` to be 33.3%.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space in the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap.

In this case, with `flex-basis: 26%`, a maximum of three items can exist on the line, there's plenty of space left for margins, and `flex-grow` fills any gaps.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child__wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 26%;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child__wrapper">1</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">2</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">3</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">4</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">5</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">6</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">7</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">8</div>
  <div class="child__wrapper">9</div>
</div>
```